# Github action how to remove starting 'v' from variable

Tags: github-actions

I have an workflow to publish nuget package on a release event, but i'm not able to strip the 'v' char from tagname. All my tag names are v${version} so i need to strip that 'v' and get the version only.

I'm with this workflow:

```
name: Nuget package publish

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:

  nuget:
    name: Nuget - Publish package
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Verify commit exists in origin/master
        run: |
          git fetch --no-tags --prune --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
          git branch --remote --contains | grep origin/master
      - name: Set VERSION variable from tag
        run: | 
          echo "VERSION=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "VERSION=${VERSION:1}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release
      - name: Pack
        run: dotnet pack UVtools.Core --configuration Release --no-build --output .
      - name: Push nuget.org
        run: dotnet nuget push UVtools.Core.${VERSION}.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${NUGET_TOKEN}
    env:
      NUGET_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }}
```

Problem at:

> Run echo "VERSION=v3.2.0" >> $GITHUB_ENV
> echo "VERSION=v3.2.0" >> $GITHUB_ENV
> echo "VERSION=${VERSION:1}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
> shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}

On my attempt to strip the 'v' VERSION is set to empty

> error: File does not exist (UVtools.Core..nupkg).

How could i strip the 'v' from variable?

PS: Under a bash script on my machine i tested:

```
VERSION=v1.5.0
echo $VERSION
echo "${VERSION:1}"
```

Which produces:

> v1.5.0
> 1.5.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer from @timmeinerzhagen works, but to make sure only a possible "v" prefix will be stripped out, you can use:

```
TAG=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
echo "VERSION=${TAG#v}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: I can't get this to work... `The term 'TAG=v1.0.0-beta-1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,`

Comment: @JobaDiniz is your runner image based on Ubuntu, as in the original question?

Comment: indeed... it was _windows_... I changed the parameter `shell` to bash and it worked, thanks

Comment: this does not work Sep 2023, `>> $GITHUB_ENV ` does not change environment in future steps

Comment: according to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-writing-an-environment-variable-to-github_env, this still works if you want to use the value in subsequent steps of the same job

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to follow up with a version that is even simpler and works as of 2022.

```yaml
# Store the version, stripping any v-prefix
- name: Write release version
  run: |
    VERSION=${GITHUB_REF_NAME#v}
    echo Version: $VERSION
    echo "VERSION=$VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV

# Use version in other step
- name: Read version
  run: echo Version now: ${VERSION}
```

The `GITHUB_REF_NAME` will contain the name of the tag. When your `on`-part looks like this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

Comment: I can't get this to work... `The term 'VERSION=v1.0.0-beta-1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,`

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to export the initial version string to the environment. It seems like the second call is not able locate it correctly in your example.

This works just fine in GitHub Actions:

```
VERSION=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
echo "VERSION=${VERSION:1}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try that on my next release. BTW is there anyway to test actions without the real event? For example try this without a release?

Comment: Tiago: you could use a `workflow_dispatch` event trigger with a `tag` or `version` input. Or even a `push` event trigger, hardcoding the tag / veraion variable for tests.

Comment: how to "parse" the tag with _prefix_ and _suffix_? Like `v1.0.0-beta-1` would be `prefix=1.0.0`, `suffix=beta-1`